# How to find a substring after a string in a file and increment that number using sed/awk in shell scipting?

Tags: awk, sed, sh

I have a abc.toml file having following content :

```
[env]
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'loy'
    COMPONENT_NAME = 'web-loy'
    AAAS_VERSION='0.0.2'
    AAAS_FLAVOR='apache-base'
    CONF_VERSION='0.0.1'
    SERVICE_VERSION='0.0.2'
```

I want to write a script in shell so that I can call it and increment the version no. in CONF_VERSION.
i.e After calling script, CONF_VERSION should become '0.0.2', and next time '0.0.3' and so on...

Expected output after calling the script once is:

```
[env]
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'loy'
    COMPONENT_NAME = 'web-loy'
    AAAS_VERSION='0.0.2'
    AAAS_FLAVOR='apache-base'
    CONF_VERSION='0.0.2'
    SERVICE_VERSION='0.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will increment the last digit for `CONF_VERSION`

```
awk '/CONF_VERSION/ {split($2,a,".");++a[3];$0=$1FS a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]FS}1' FS="'" file
[env]
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'loy'
    COMPONENT_NAME = 'web-loy'
    AAAS_VERSION='0.0.2'
    AAAS_FLAVOR='apache-base'
    CONF_VERSION='0.0.2'
    SERVICE_VERSION='0.0.2'
```

PS you do not write what should happen after `0.0.9`.  This `awk` gives `0.0.10`

Edit:

```
awk '/CONF_VERSION/ {split($2,a,".");if (a[3]==9) {a[3]=0;++a[2]} else {++a[3]};$0=$1FS a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]FS}1' FS="'" file
```

This version will change from `0.0.9` to `0.1.0` and not `0.0.10`

Comment: The output right now is :  CONF_VERSION='0.0.2  What should be edited to get output as  CONF_VERSION='0.0.2'

Comment: @HarshitGoel You can do this `awk 'code' abc.toml > tmp && mv tmp abc.toml`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another awk version:

```
$ awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml
[env]
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'loy'
    COMPONENT_NAME = 'web-loy'
    AAAS_VERSION='0.0.2'
    AAAS_FLAVOR='apache-base'
    CONF_VERSION='0.0.2'
    SERVICE_VERSION='0.0.2'
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[.]'`

  This tells awk to use `.` as the field separator for input.
- `/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"}`

  This selects only lines which contain `CONF_VERSION=`.  For those lines, the third field is incremented by 1 and a single quote is appended.

  `\x27` means a single quote.  It is expressed this way so as not to confuse the shell.
- `1`

  This tells awk to print the line.
- `OFS=.`

  This tells awk to use a period as the field separator for output.

#### To update in-place

If you have GNU awk (sometimes called gawk), use:

```
gawk -i inplace -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml
```

The following will update in place regardless of the awk version:

```
awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml >temp && mv temp abc.toml
```

Comment: To update the file abc.toml also I am using :awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml > abc.toml But it is not working. How can I update the file also and not printing on console?

Comment: @HarshitGoel I just added to the end of the answer two methods for updating the file instead of printing on the console.

Comment: After running this, I am getting an out put like this:    Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options: (standard)
        -f progfile             --file=progfile  gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

Comment: @HarshitGoel Oops.  I had a typo in the second version.  Try the corrected version `awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$3=($3+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml >temp && mv temp`

Comment: "It is expressed this way so as not to confuse the shell." ... well, you don't want to confuse the shell, but it provides a literal single-quote that will not have any significance to the shell other than being just a character.

Comment: Thanks @John1024 That really helped :)

Comment: @John1024 If we have to increment second field, I am using 
awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$2=($2+1)"\x27"} 1' OFS=. abc.toml

But after updation, following output is coming :
CONF_VERSION='0.1'.2'

But it should be CONF_VERSION='0.1.2'
Can you please help?

Comment: @HarshitGoel To increment the second field only, try: `awk -F'[.]' '/CONF_VERSION=/{$2=($2+1)} 1' OFS=. abc.toml`